# VS2013 C# Program runs OK on Workstation but gets error on Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I created a C# program and created the release folder with all non .NET dlls and the exe.  It runs fine in development and standalone locally on Windows 7.  I put the Release folder on the Windows Server (2012).
I can run the exe from any workstation (Windows 7) just fine using a shortcut.  If I try to run the exe directly on the Windows 2012 server itself it gives a [`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx) error.

The program is targeting .Net framework 4.5.

Why does it run on the workstation but not on the server?

The file not found message does NOT tell you what file is not found.

Also any ideas on how to find out what file is not found besides this generic message:

[image: Error]

[image: Event Log]

Comment: Exception error message should also tell you which file can't be found...

Comment: It looks like it is trying to find a file which is not pathed properly on the server or a file which does not exist on the server.

Comment: The exception message does not tell what file is not found.  All files needed are in the release folder as confirmed when you run it from a workstation.  It is a simple application.

Comment: _"The exception message does not tell what file is not found"_. Can you please post such message any way? Note it's also generated if a native dependency can't be found. _"All files needed are in the release folder as confirmed when you run it from a workstation."_ Well then run-time is wrong and you may simply ignore that exception! solved!

Comment: If you can't find the exception detail it might be worth looking in the Event Log. Any unhandled framework exceptions are logged in there (assuming it is unhandled of course!)

Comment: Does that Win2012 server have .Net Framework version 4.5 installed?

Comment: Yes, Windows server does have 4.5 framework installed

Comment: That's not exception error message. Go to find it in events log (if it's not displayed anywhere else in your application).

Comment: I would love to ignore the exception on the server except the powers that be seem to think it is a problem.  Running on the workstation is not enough.  I also assume it should run correctly on the server.  I also assume it could be a rights issue where the workstation has certain rights that running from the server does not.

Comment: Also I have no access to the event log.  I am a programmer with no administration access to the server getting the error so appreciate all the help I can get without the down votes or smart comments like Davids.  I am groping for knowledge to form an attack on this problem and I know this question technique does not sit well with SO philosophy but it is real life for me.

Comment: see if your server admins will let you or someone else run Process Monitor on the server where the error is occurring - it should help you identify the file that cannot be found. I've often used it to diagnose issues like this in different deployment environments.

Comment: _"I am a programmer with no administration access to the server"_ - so how do you expect us to help? We don't have your software nor server, so we can't reproduce the error. If they want you to fix it, they must give you proper access to the machine.

Comment: Does the application attempt to load a file from the filesystem anywhere that doesn't exist on the server. I know that seems pretty obvious, but the amount I have been stumped by the obvious, its still worth checking. This would likely be a hard coded string, or a filepath in the app.config file. Make sure there is no paths still pointing to your local machine

Comment: David Watts is correct and that is also one of my suspicions since posting this.  It does have a path to a database file and one possibility is that on the server it does not have rights to find the file but on the workstation it does.  I do not think that is the cause though but not excluding it as a possibility. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, CodeCaster - 100% correct.  Can you please call my boss and let them know too!  lol.  I expect the professionals to help by telling me places to look or things to consider.  I know I can check the error log but is there any other tools to debug this.  Considering the mix of windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 and the client server aspect is there any experience that can opened up to solve this.  Any VS 2013 configuration setting amiss or log setting.  Ect...  I did not say this was an easy solve with all the details spelled out.  It is real life.

Comment: I added a picture of the Event Log taken from a Windows 8 machine that throws an exception when running the program.